# About the point $P$ inside a square $ABCD$ satisfying $BP = BC$ and $\angle APD = 90^\circ$

Tags: geometry

There is a problem I'm trying to solve from the Polish *XI Olimpiada Matematyczna Gimnazjalistów*. It is question 2 from [this document](http://www.omg.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap15.pdf). (The deadline of 12 October 2015 has passed.)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHRwy.jpg]

So far I found $x^2$ and $y^2$ (that are $|AP|^2$ and $|PD|^2$).

In order to prove, that AP=2PD, can I just divide
$$
\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y^2}}
$$
and show, that it equals $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, we may assume that 
$$A(0,1),B(0,0),C(1,0),D(1,1).$$

Let $P(p,q)$. Now $P$ is on the circle whose diameter is the line segment $AD$, so
$$\left(p-\frac 12\right)^2+(q-1)^2=\frac 14\tag1$$
Also, since $BP=1$, one has
$$p^2+q^2=1\tag2$$
Solving $(1)(2)$ with $0\lt q\lt 1$ gives $(p,q)=\left(\frac 45,\frac 35\right)$.

Now, it follows from $AP^2=\frac 45$ and $PD^2=\frac 15$ that $AP=2PD$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am adding a better solution below.

I. (original method)  Without loss of generality, assume the square has sides of length $1$.

Let $x=AP$.  Angle chasing shows that $$<BPA =<BAP=<PDA$$  Call this common angle $\theta$.

Clearly $x=sin(\theta)$

The law of Cosines tells us that $$x^2=2+2cos(2\theta)=4-4sin^2(\theta)$$

And the desired claim follows at once.

II.  (better method)

Draw the perpendicular from $B$ to $AP$, call the foot $Q$.  It is clear, from angle chasing, that $\Delta BQP$ is congruent to both  $\Delta BQA$ and $\Delta APD$.  The claim follows at once.